# How ignore video when import media to Lightroom (not uncheck every time, full ignored)

Tags: lightroom, video, lightroom-catalog, adobe, import

When I import photos Lightroom import videos too, but how ignore video files or files by extension without press every time "Uncheck videos" at import dialog?

*Uncheck videos button shown if press alt (windows) at import dialog*

Lightroom Classic CC 8.2 Release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's the only way right now, until Adobe adds an option in the future to auto ignore video files.

It takes a second using the option/alt key, can understand why it was never really requested.